# Can't set DataTables column width on a dynamically generated table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have some jquery that posts some data, gets a list back as a JSON response and builds a datatable based on the list data. Everything works well, however I have one seemingly simple issue:
I cannot get the column widths in my table declaration to to persist.

My code looks something like this:

```
//some magic happens and I get a result like this
json_result = ['eggs', 'bananas', 'purple']

//declare the table
var result_table = $( table_selector )
table = result_table.DataTable({
              //set two different width columns
              columnDefs: [
                     { "width": "10%", "targets": 0 },
                     { "width": "90%", "targets": 1 }
                    ]
          });

//build the table rows based on result
for (i=0, i<json_result.length, i++){
    var new_row = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>' +json_result[i] + '</td></tr>'
    table.row.add(new_row).draw();
   }

// table.columns.adjust().draw(); <-- tried this to no avail
table.draw();
```

The result is a perfectly good table that fits well in it's container...but the column widths are split 50/50. These same column defs seem to work fine on other tables in my application. I feel like I'm missing something simple!

Comment: Have you tried this? https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/4374/#Comment_4374

Comment: Woah, that totally worked. I incorrectly  figured that had to do with the overall size of the table, not the actual inner widths. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad it worked. I have added an answer for those who might follow you and not read the comments. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a forum thread here [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/4374/#Comment_4374), disable the "auto width" functionality via:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bAutoWidth": false
  } );
} );
```

Reference: [legacy.datatables.net](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features#bAutoWidth):